# How can create a settle transaction immediate after create a transaction /make a payment without waiting for 24 hours to settle it

Tags: magento, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

How can we settle the transaction immediate after payment from CIM Authorize.net

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Authorize.net settles one per day (overnight actually) and the timing cannot be changed. There is no way to manually settle transactions.

Comment: Settlement occurs once each day starting after the transaction cut-off time specified in the merchant interface.

Comment: Terrible design by Authorize.net IMHO. My recommendation: don't use Authorize.net if you can avoid it. Their UI for managing payments is also very inflexible, searching transactions is strange, etc.